# ng-show does not work with custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I've just started using AngularJS and wanted to create a custom template directive for creating "in-place" editable tables. The idea would be to have something like:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in model.customers">
        <ng-template ng-hide="customer === model.selectedCustomer"> <!-- display template-->
            <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ng-show="customer === model.selectedCustomer"> <!-- edit template -->
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="customer.name"/></td>
        </ng-template>
    </tr>
```

It could then also be extended to specify a templateUrl e.g. `<ng-template template-url="foo.html"></ng-template>`

When I apply the `ng-show` directive to my custom directive it does not work. Here's the code for my directive:

```
var demo = angular.module("demo", [])
.directive("ng-template", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true
    }
});
```

and HTML (http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/ASXyy/):

```
<div ng-app="demo">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="name in ['jane', 'john', 'frank']">
            <ng-template ng-show="name !== 'frank'">
                <td>{{name}}</td>
            </ng-template>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Furthermore, when I look at the generated HTML my custom directive doesn't even appear in the table:

```
<div ng-app="demo" class="ng-scope">
    <ng-template ng-show="name !== 'frank'" class="">
    </ng-template>
    <table>   
        <tbody>
          ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Essentially I'm trying to avoid writing code like this (setting the `ng-show` directive on every `<td>` element):

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <ng-template>
            <td ng-hide="isSelected">{{customer.name}}</td>
            <td ng-hide="isSelected">{{customer.age}}</td>
            <td ng-hide="isSelected"><button ng-click="edit(customer)"</td>
            <td ng-show="isSelected"><input type="text" ng-model="customer.name"/></td>
            <td ng-show="isSelected"><input type="text" ng-model="customer.age"/></td>
            <td ng-show="isSelected"><button ng-click="save(customer)"</td>
        </ng-template>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: imo it's not a good idea name custom directive with a ng-prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things occur to me when I look at your code.

1. ng-include offers very similar functionality to your proposal for extending ng-template.  If you're going to load a view based on the state of the underlying model then I think this would be the way to go.
2. If you're not going to be loading the template from a separate view file, why not just use ng-show (or ng-if / ng-switch, which I prefer in most cases) on your td element?

Here is some example code using ng-include:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="getTemplate(item)"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the full JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qQR6j/2.

Comment: Thanks, but
1. ng-include doesn't work inside a `<tr>` or `<table>` element.
2. As I've stated a number of times now, this would require the ng-show/hide/if directives on every `<td>` inside the row.

Comment: OK, I didn't know (1) - sounds odd.  Why don't you just have ng-show/ng-hide/ng-if/etc on your <tr> instead then?

Comment: I was intrigued by your suggestion that ng-include doesn't work inside a table, and came up with the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/qQR6j/2/

Seems to work fine as far as I can tell?

Comment: I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before :/ but that looks like a nice solution. I'll update my new fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/5RELP/) to see which option I prefer. As for not having the ng-show/etc. on the <tr> this results in the "edit" option always appearing at the bottom of the table.

Comment: After checking out your example (I'd recommend updating your answer with the code) I think this is the cleaner solution. My updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/UWLFJ/

Comment: Thanks - I've added the relevant view code to the post and included a link to the full fiddle (seemed a bit much to paste all of the code!).

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to specify the two alternative `<tr>` tags.

```
<div ng-app="demo">
    <table ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <tr ng-repeat-start="name in ['jane', 'john', 'frank']" ng-hide="isSelected(name)">
            <td>{{name}} <button ng-click="select(name)">edit</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="isSelected(name)">
            <td>{{name}}!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

With this javascript

```
var demo = angular.module("demo", []);

demo.controller("Ctrl",
function Ctrl($scope) {
    var selected;
    $scope.isSelected = function(name) {
        return selected === name;
    };
    $scope.select = function(name) {
        selected = name;
    };
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6FtjG/1/

Comment: This is the best/only solution I've seen so far that worked. I'm not sure it's what ng-repeat-start/end was designed for but it's better than repeating the ng-show/hide declarations on every td element. My completed fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/5RELP/

Answer (score 1):

Your browser renders the 'ng-template' outside of the table because its not a valid child of tr. Even if you have set replace to true, the directive needs to be rendered before it can be replaced.

You can see it is because of the table, because this does work:

```
 <div>
    <div ng-repeat="name in ['jane', 'john', 'frank']">
        <ng-template ng-show="name !== 'frank'">
            <div >{{name}}</div>
        </ng-template>            
    </div>
</div>
```

see: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASXyy/4/)

This is something your browser does so you cannot avoid it.

Comment: No, as I explained in my question I want to create an in-place editable table with a "display" template and an "edit" template. The `ng-show` condition in my example is just to demonstrate that it is not working.